# understanding and implementing voice recognition for eclipse on android app

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am currently working on an app and I need to be able to have the user control the app with nothing but their voice if necessary. I got a copy of some speech recognition code that apparently comes from android and I tried using it in my app. The code itself appears fairly simple but I need help understanding a few parts and implementing it on the app. I have ran the app on an android device and when I use the speech I get a list of phrases I possibly said. I want to be able to set up and activity where if one of the results is "close app" for example it will close the app. I thought I could set this up by doing an if statement for the results of the voice recognizer. Such as if results == close app then run the activity close. I don't have any of this set up because I'm not sure how to code it exactly but I thought some of you would have some ideas.

```
package com.example.com.proto1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


    /**
     * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
     */
    public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

        private ListView mList;

        /**
         * Called with the activity is first created.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
            setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);

            // Get display items for later interaction
            Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

            mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
            if (activities.size() != 0) {
                speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            } else {
                speakButton.setEnabled(false);
                speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
         */
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
         */
        private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        /**
         * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
                ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        matches));
            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is results you have received from voice recognition activity:

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

`matches` is a list of possible texts that you have pronounced. If you want to close your app when some magic phrase was said you need something like this:

```
if (matches.contains("close")) {
     finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go beyond string comparison, you might try stemming or phonetic matching.

You will need that in order to make your recognition even more accurate or if you have some hard-to-recognize words.

Check out the code [here](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/tree/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/text) which implements stemming and phonetic matching. The other parts of the code use the matching for speech recognition. There's also this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Greg-Milette/e/B00851G18G) if you want to know all the details.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm going to vote you up since this is helpful. For now however, I only need very simple commands so I don't need this yet.

Comment: Even for simple commands, you'll need the boiler plate code to get going.